# How to use props defined by type guards in lower scopes without re-defining type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, destructuring

Suppose you have the following React/Typescript code in the link below. Because the props in this component include a union and intersection, I'm using type guards to destructure the props. When I use one of these destructured props in a render function `renderCompany`, I get the following error: `Variable 'companyId' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

The obvious way out of this is to declare `companyId` as a number but we would end up defining the type for that variable twice, once in the prop types and another when declared. How can I use this variable in a different scope without re-defining the type?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-y82qzc

```
type WrongInfoProps = (
  | WrongInfoCompanyProps
  | WrongInfoPersonProps
  | WrongInfoBranchProps
) &
  WrongInfoCallbackProps;

interface WrongInfoCallbackProps {
  onClose: (isModalOpen?: boolean) => void;
}

interface WrongInfoCompanyProps {
  companyId: number;
}

interface WrongInfoBranchProps {
  branchId: number;
  branchName: string;
  companyId: number;
  parentName: string;
}

interface WrongInfoPersonProps {
  employmentId: number;
  execId: number;
  companyName: string;
}

export default function App(props: WrongInfoProps) {
  let branchId,
    companyId,
    branchName,
    parentName,
    execId,
    employmentId,
    companyName;
  if ("branchId" in props) {
    ({ branchId, companyId, branchName, parentName } = props);
  } else if ("companyId" in props) {
    ({ companyId } = props);
  } else if ("execId" in props) {
    ({ execId, employmentId, companyName } = props);
  }

  const renderCompany = () => {
    return <div>{companyId}</div>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{renderCompany()}</h1>
      <div>{companyId}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Destructuring `props` like this throws out all the type-safety the union is giving you. The compiler is rightfully trying to warn you about this. You should only destructure the shared properties and directly access `props` to get the other ones after narrowing appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to access a member of an interface, that looks like this:

```
WrongInfoProps["companyId"] // number
```

This component is doing a lot of work to obfuscate any decently declarative patterns. Why are there so many shapes? Typescript is for removing runtime errors by declarative means. Save yourself (and your future colleagues) some headache and break this up into "dumb" components. The "smarter" your components try to be, to more likely they will be difficult to test.

There are also problems with `renderCompany()`.

- Why are you defining a function inside the render body? React is much better at rendering functions with `tsx`. Use a new component `<Company />` and compartmentalize the behavior of rendering a company inside there. If you truly need to define a callback renderer, do it with `useMemo` so you aren't "dumb" rendering on every reflow.
- Why do you need to join so many types? One main goal of typescript is to clarify the types of values that are being passed around. I can't reason with your types because they're anything.

It looks like you need to define more components. I would suggest 3 separate components; one for each "job" your `App` has. Your job will be easier if you compartmentalize your component responsibilities.

```
<WrongInfoBranch />
<WrongInfoCompany />
<WrongInfoPerson />
```

Taking it one step further, I would suggest a context. You could be helped by a custom provider to store your state. Here is an example with context. This also solves your problem of drilling props:

```
const WrongInfoContext = React.createContext<{
  company?: WrongInfoCompanyProps
  person?: WrongInfoPersonProps
  branch?: WrongInfoBranchProps
}>({
  company: undefined,
  person: undefined,
  branch: undefined,
})

function App() {
  /* do all your state stuff
  const company = useMemo(() => ({ ... }), [])
  const person = useMemo(() => ({ ... }), [])
  const branch = useMemo(() => ({ ... }), [])
  */
  return (
    <WrongInfoContext.Provider value={{ company, person, branch }}>
      {company && <WrongInfoCompany />}
      {person && <WrongInfoPerson />}
      {branch && <WrongInfoBranch />}
    </WrongInfoContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Afterwards you don't need to pass props. your Context knows if something is defined and what the shape is. You can now use your shape anywhere.

```
function WrongInfoCompany(/*No props!*/) {
  const company = React.useContext(WrongInfoContext).company
  // undefined || { companyId: number, ... }
  // ...
}
```

If you follow these patterns, you won't have any type re-declaration issues.